# Grow baby/dward bananas from pots?

Tags: fruit-trees, containers, banana

I live in the Caribbean and my house has a rooftop that receives sun approx 12hrs during the day. It's usually 80-95 degrees. There's no soil so any plant would grow in a pot. There's very little shade, mainly from the building next to me.

I would like to have several banana trees in this rooftop. I would prefer baby/dwarf bananas.

I've called several local places, and nobody sells seeds or plants that grow dwarf/baby bananas.

Where online can I buy high-quality seeds or plants that will grow dwarf/baby bananas in pots? I've seen many online stores that sell them, but I don't know if they have good reputation.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: How sure are you that the roof is weight bearing? Can 6 people stand on it safely? Pots, soil and plants are extremely heavy...

Comment: @GrahamChiu: Please clarify what needs clarifying.

Comment: @Bamboo: Yes, it's weight-bearing.

Comment: What is the exact question you are asking?